# iOS5 CSS scaling on orientation change

Tags: css, mobile

Check out this site on an (iOS5) iPad: http://viewpoint.ca/mobilemap

I must've done something recently, but after undoing a bunch of things that I changed, I can't seem to find the issue.

If you change the orientation, the page scales instead of re-sizing and results in some really weird stretching.

As soon as you focus on a form element, then it goes back to normal....Does anybody know what this is?

Any suggestions/help is greatly appreciated here.

Answer (score 0):

My bet would be the second viewport meta tag - maybe try putting: width=device-width in there as well.

Also, I'd change the id of the second one, as you should have to elements with the same id.

Finally - I don't recall ever seeing a meta tag with a media attribute. I'm not sure that works how you are expecting it to. You can probably safely get rid of one of those declarations...

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've commented out each one individually and both on my dev site to see if it made a difference, but commenting out one of the other didn't make a difference, and commenting out both resulted in undesireable scaling on initial load. You're right about the ID issue, it's not legal HTML and I will change it, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Interestingly, it seems to work ok on iOS6. (Not that useful, but an extra data point). Good luck!